# MariaDB: problems in installaation to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mariadb

This is a very newbie question but I guess it's OK since I am rather new Ubuntu Linux user and now trying to install MariaDB to my computer.

I am using Ubuntu version 14.04 and my problem is that first I chose to install a wrong version (utopic) of MariaDB. My Ubuntu version does not support that I guess and now when I am trying to install install the correct version (trusty) I get an error saying

```
mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.16+maria-1~utopic) but 10.0.16+maria-1~utopic is to be installed
```

Could someone help me and tell what should I do and how?

Thank you already in advance!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy mariadb-server-10.0; lsb_release -a; grep -r 'utopic' /etc/apt`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that only `trusty` entries are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You may use this default `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then try

```
sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Comment: `purge` removes all configurations, too. That's a bad idea.